# How do I add a suffix to a column range in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a punctuation mark at the end of every question in my dataframe. Each question is a column name. Since there are a lot of questions I decided to slice the dataframe using

```
df2.iloc[:, 59:125]
```

The code that I am using is:

```
df2.iloc[:, 59:125].add_suffix(".")
```

Ouput shows that this line does add a punctuation mark to the questions:

```
df2.iloc[:, 59:125].add_suffix(".")
Out[69]: 
    I would recommend this company as a great place to work .  ...  
    What one change would make the biggest positive difference to you being able to perform your role effectively?.
```

but when I save it as an excel file and check, none of the 66 questions have been updated.

I have also tried:

```
 [10270 rows x 66 columns]

df2.iloc[:, 59:125] = (df2.iloc[:, 59:125].add_suffix("."))

df2.iloc[:, 59:125] = (df2.iloc[:, 59:125].add_suffix("."))

print(df2.iloc[:, 59:125])
       I would recommend this company as a great place to work   ...  What one change would make the biggest positive difference to you being able to perform your role effectively?
```

If you notice, there is no punctuation mark at the end of the questions displayed. Meaning that this code does not update the dataframe.

Comment: In the second case, you're correctly assigning to `df` but you print `df2`.

Comment: ah, yes I noticed that, but strangely enough it doesn't seem to affect the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `enumerate` the column headers and reassign it if the header index is in desired range

```py
lst = range(59, 125)

df = df.rename(columns={col: col+'.'
                        for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns)
                        if idx in lst})
# or
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(col, '.' if idx in lst else '')
              for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Could I ask why the method I was trying was not updating my dataframe?

Comment: @Scythor My understanding is that `df2.iloc[:, 59:125]` selects part of dataframe from original dataframe. While `df2.iloc[:, 59:125].add_suffix(".")` returns a dataframe just change the column header. Assigning dataframe to part of original dataframe will update the value where index and column header matches. Since the column header is different, so nothing changes.

Comment: so although `df2.iloc[:, 59:125].add_suffix(".")` only returns the columns I specified, it does not update the dataframe. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the fuction `add.suffix`? I tried using `regex=True` and `inplace=True` but cannot be used with add.suffix.

Comment: @Scythor Its purpose is to add suffix to all columns and return the updated dataframe. There is no such argument like regex or inplace for [pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html)